# Reusable controlled input using useController being called in a form that contains other fields. TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

From the `useController` hook [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller), we get this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontroller-0o8px

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm, useController, UseControllerProps } from "react-hook-form";
import Headers from "./Header";
import "./styles.css";

type FormValues = {
  FirstName: string;
};

let renderCount = 0;

function Input(props: UseControllerProps<FormValues>) {
  const { field, fieldState } = useController(props);

  return (
    <div>
      <input {...field} placeholder={props.name} />
      <p>{fieldState.isTouched && "Touched"}</p>
      <p>{fieldState.isDirty && "Dirty"}</p>
      <p>{fieldState.invalid ? "invalid" : "valid"}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      FirstName: ""
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
  const onSubmit = (data: FormValues) => console.log(data);
  renderCount++;

  return (
    <div>
      <Headers
        renderCount={renderCount}
        description="Performant, flexible and extensible forms with easy-to-use validation."
      />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Input control={control} name="FirstName" rules={{ required: true }} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically we have a reusable controlled input for the `firstName` and the `App` component that calls `useForm` and passes the control to it.

I was able to achieve that behavior.

But what happens if your form needs to also implement other fields: maybe more controlled/uncontrolled fields.

If we update the example to split the types between the input and the form types, we get an error in the `control={control}` prop.

For example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontroller-forked-x02jxz

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm, useController, UseControllerProps } from "react-hook-form";
import Headers from "./Header";
import "./styles.css";

type InputValues = {     // TYPES FOR THE CONTROLLED INPUT
  FirstName: string;
};

let renderCount = 0;

function Input(props: UseControllerProps<InputValues>) {
  const { field, fieldState } = useController(props);

  return (
    <div>
      <input {...field} placeholder={props.name} />
      <p>{fieldState.isTouched && "Touched"}</p>
      <p>{fieldState.isDirty && "Dirty"}</p>
      <p>{fieldState.invalid ? "invalid" : "valid"}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

type FormValues = {     // TYPES FOR THE WHOLE FORM
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      FirstName: ""
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
  const onSubmit = (data: FormValues) => console.log(data);
  renderCount++;

  return (
    <div>
      <Headers
        renderCount={renderCount}
        description="Performant, flexible and extensible forms with easy-to-use validation."
      />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Input control={control} name="FirstName" rules={{ required: true }} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We get the following error:

> Type 'Control<FormValues, object>' is not assignable to type 'Control<InputValues, object>'.

[image]

I imagine that this a pretty common scenario, but I'm not sure how to proceed form here. Most of the examples illustrates as if the controlled `InputTypes` would be the same as the `FullFormTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit Input function tyopes to:

```
function Input(props: UseControllerProps<FormValues, "FirstName" | "LastName">): JSX.Element{
....
}
```

It works like clockwork for you!